# How do I convert a byte to an integer in python when it has the byte markers attached?

Tags: python, python-3.x, integer, hex, byte

I have a function in python which reads the first 3 bytes in a serial port buffer. I then want to convert the third byte to an integer which will allow me to determine the length of the total byte array. However, when I use `int()` I get the following error:

`ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 16: b'\x16'`

I've tried slicing the string further along, but that just returns b''. How can I convert the byte to an integer?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `int.from_bytes()`.

> >>> `int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='big')`
>
> `16`
>
> >>> `int.from_bytes(b'\x00\x10', byteorder='little')`
>
> `4096`
>
> >>> `int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=True)`
>
> `-1024`
>
> >>> `int.from_bytes(b'\xfc\x00', byteorder='big', signed=False)`
>
> `64512`
>
> >>> `int.from_bytes([255, 0, 0], byteorder='big')`
>
> `16711680`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Python 3, you can just index the byte array and use the value directly as an integer. e.g.

```
>>> v = b"\0\1\2"
>>> v[2]
2
>>> v[2] + 1
3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [stuct](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) module. But it work with 4 bytes (int)

```
import struct

(length,) = struct.unpack('!I', my_binary)
```